# C++ How to expose a map iterator to only the values of a map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stl, iterator

I have some templates which can either have a map or a vector as underlying container. I would like the template to be able to expose const iterators to the elements. Most information I have read on how to expose iterators (such as [this accu article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1527)) uses a form of

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iterator;
typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;
iterator begin() { return values.begin(); }
iterator end() { return values.end(); }
```

That doesn't really work for the template that uses the map though, because to access elements, the template can't use `it->SomeMemberFunc()` anymore, but rather needs to use `it->second.SomeMemberFunc()`. So I am looking to expose an iterator to the map elements which doesn't give access to the `keys` but only the values of the map.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: See [boost::adaptors::map_values](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html).

Comment: Depending on what you're using those iterators for, it might be easier to just provide (instead of iterators) a for_each style member function that does a callback for all elements. You could easily specialize that for the map version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround<sup>[1](http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-iterate-over-values-of-stdmap.html)</sup>

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iter>
struct map_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                      typename Iter::value_type::second_type> 
{
    map_iterator() {}
    map_iterator(Iter j) : i(j) {}
    map_iterator& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
    map_iterator& operator--() { --i; return *this; }
    bool operator==(map_iterator j) const { return i == j.i; }
    bool operator!=(map_iterator j) const { return !(*this == j); }
    typename map_iterator::reference operator*() { return i->second; }
    typename map_iterator::pointer operator->() { return &i->second; }
    map_iterator operator--(int) { return std::prev(--(*this)); }
    map_iterator operator++(int) { return std::next((++*this)); }
protected:
    Iter i;
};

template <typename Iter>
inline map_iterator<Iter> make_map_iterator(Iter j) {
    return map_iterator<Iter>(j);
}
```

And then

```
int main() {
    std::map<int,std::string> m {{1, "Hi"},{2, "Bye"}};

    for (auto i=make_map_iterator(m.begin()); i!=make_map_iterator(m.end());i++)
        cout << *i << endl;
}
```

*[Live code.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5049498d278a349)*

Comment: Perfect. Re. the post increments, are these actually correct as they stand? Seem to be going back twice and forward twice, and the brackets are different once...

Comment: @Cookie: Thanks, the current post is correct to use. I've just tried to minimize the lines of code.